# OCaml: Going from int list list to int

Tags: unix, ocaml

I am working on a OCaml motion detection program. It analyzes two images and detects if there was motion. One part requires me summing a row of values and then also summing an entire image. This is what I have currenly:

```
let rec sumImRow(maskedrow) = 
 match maskedrow with 
   | [] -> 0
   | mskRhd::mskRtl -> mskRhd + (sumImRow mskRtl)
   ;;

let rec sumImage(maskedimage) =
 match maskedimage with
   | mskRhd::mskRtl -> (sumImRow mskRhd)::(sumImage mskRtl)
   | _ -> [] 
   ;;
```

and the given value is `int list list -> int list = <fun>`.
I don't quite understand why this is giving me `int list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: You construct a new list instead of summing the integers.

Well, we can agree that `sumImRow` has type `int list -> int` as it takes elements from the list and then return their sum.

`sumImage` will have a `list` argument as it deconstructs it in the pattern matching. It then returns the `list` of result of `sumImRow`, meaning `sumImage` gets as argument a list of what `sumImRow` takes and returns a list of results. So we indeed have `int list list -> int list`.

You can avoid that by replacing `::` with `+` and `[]` with `0` in `sumImage`'s matching result.

You can also make a more improved code by using `List.fold_left`:

```
let sumImRow l = List.fold_left (+) 0 l;;
let sumImage l = List.fold_left (List.fold_left (+)) 0 l;;
```

Answer (score 0):

The two return values of `sumImage` are both lists. So naturally its return type is a list.

(Most likely you should be using `+` rather than `::` in sumImage. And the base case should be `0` rather than `[]`.)